# Customer creation and create order taking time in Magento2.4.5

Tags: email, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.6

I configured the server email in my Magento project, but I noticed that it takes a long time to create customers and process orders. Upon investigating the issue, I found that the delay occurs in the **mailHandler** function within the file `vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php.`

I'm wondering if there is a missing configuration or if anyone else has encountered a similar problem and found a solution.

**Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify the SMTP configurations and is that works with Laminas

https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/laminas-mail-smtp-unable-to-resolve-service-to-a-factory/2166

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I will check and let you know. +1

Comment: it's working thank you.... :)